# View all comments on a YouTube video

Tags: java, youtube

I am trying to get all the comments on a YouTube video using a Java program. I cannot get them though as it has the "Show More" instead of all the comments. I'm looking for a way to get all the comments or pages of comments that I can go through. I have a video id and things, just need the comments.

I have tried all_comments instead of watch in the URL but it doesn't show all comments still and redirects to watch again.

I have also looked at the YouTube api and can only find how to get comments with their id but I need to get all comments from a video id.

If anyone knows how to do this please tell me.

I have added a 50 rep bounty for whoever can give me a good answer to this.

Comment: interesting im also looking forward for an answer

Comment: Hmm. If it is not answered in 6 hours I'm going to put a bounty on.

Comment: Now probably everybody is just waiting for the bounty to be set :D

Comment: I don't mind, as long as it is answered that is all I care about.

Comment: Bounty is now added!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list Check total number of pages. Write a loop and make incremental calls

Comment: can you figure out how this is doing that? this seems to get all the comments for a video: http://www.sandracires.com/en/client/youtube/random.htm?todo=submit&v=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DYcZkCnPs45s

Comment: @KillBill That is using a YouTube library and is running this code
`var youtube=new YoutubeComments('YcZkCnPs45s', 13); youtube.run();` and will randomly choose a comment.

Comment: but it does iterate all the comments isnt it

Comment: @bwfcwalshy, which implementation language you need to use?

Comment: You can use this tool I made to download all youtube comments from a video as json https://youtuberandomcomment.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to get comment threads list request for your video and then scroll forward using next page token from the last response:

```
private static int counter = 0;
private static YouTube youtube;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // For Auth details consider:
    // https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/Auth.java
    // Also don't forget secrets https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json
    List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl");
    Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "commentthreads");
    youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();

    String videoId = "video_id";

    // Get video comments threads
    CommentThreadListResponse commentsPage = prepareListRequest(videoId).execute();

    while (true) {
        handleCommentsThreads(commentsPage.getItems());

        String nextPageToken = commentsPage.getNextPageToken();
        if (nextPageToken == null)
            break;

        // Get next page of video comments threads
        commentsPage = prepareListRequest(videoId).setPageToken(nextPageToken).execute();
    }

    System.out.println("Total: " + counter);
}

private static YouTube.CommentThreads.List prepareListRequest(String videoId) throws Exception {

    return youtube.commentThreads()
                  .list("snippet,replies")
                  .setVideoId(videoId)
                  .setMaxResults(100L)
                  .setModerationStatus("published")
                  .setTextFormat("plainText");
}

private static void handleCommentsThreads(List<CommentThread> commentThreads) {

    for (CommentThread commentThread : commentThreads) {
        List<Comment> comments = Lists.newArrayList();
        comments.add(commentThread.getSnippet().getTopLevelComment());

        CommentThreadReplies replies = commentThread.getReplies();
        if (replies != null)
            comments.addAll(replies.getComments());

        System.out.println("Found " + comments.size() + " comments.");

        // Do your comments logic here
        counter += comments.size();
    }
}
```

Consider [api-samples](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/java), if you need a sample skeleton project.

---

**Update**

The situation when you can't get all the comments can be also caused by the [quota limits](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) (at least I faced it):

- units/**day**                50,000,000
- units/**100seconds/user**    300,000

This is not a java, python, js, or whatever language specific rules. If you want to get above the quota, you cant try to [apply for higher quota](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/quotas). Though, I would start from controlling your throughput. It's very easy to get above the **100seconds/user** quota.

Comment: isn't there a limit to the no of comments you can crawl with this approach? i doubt that

Comment: you can limit page size with ".setMaxResults()". this is a part of their api, so you can use it in python client as well.

Comment: i mean if a video has 1M comments, can this download them all? i saw somewhere api does not support this

Comment: it uses just the same api as yours, but from java. I think the limitations are caused by quota. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed and thank you but putting details about limits and how to apply for higher ones. Much appreciated. You have been given the bounty :)

Comment: +1 are you aware of ways i can speed up the comments download speed? something like using multi threads, is that possible with the api?

Answer (score 4):

try this it can download all the comments for a given video which i have tested.

https://github.com/egbertbouman/youtube-comment-downloader

```
python downloader.py --youtubeid YcZkCnPs45s --output OUT 
Downloading Youtube comments for video: YcZkCnPs45s 
Downloaded 1170 comment(s) 
Done!
```

output is in the JSON format:

```
{
  "text": "+Tony Northrup many thanks for the prompt reply - I'll try that.﻿",
  "time": "1 day ago",
  "cid": "z13nfbog0ovqyntk322txzjamuensvpch.1455717946638546"
}
```

Comment: Yeah that one works! And without YouTube API credentials & quota limits too :-) It's a bit funny though that I'm getting german meta-values like this: {"text": "Mega Madness\ufeff", "time": "vor 1 Woche", "author": "Jessica Fischer", "cid": "z135hboyasa2j1rgy04cgdrwxmunhdvajqg0k"}

Comment: but this script gets really slow as the number of comments to download increases. YT API is much faster.

Comment: @samsamara If possible, I hope you can rewrite it with java, or give me suggestions so I can recreate it with java.

Comment: @VũĐạt I"m not the author of that script. It gets super slow as the number of comments increase anyways. Is there any reason why you can't use the YT API? I have resorted to using YT API as this script is too slow