# 403 : Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded youtube api v3 java

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I Know this question has been asked multiple times, but I couldn't find one working for me.

Basically I am trying to get a youtube video basic info which I get the proper result for that but then when I trigger to get the comments of that video the error pops out saying:

> There was a service error: 403 : Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.

My code:

```
public String getyoutubeitemfull_details(String URI) throws SQLException, IOException{
    try {
        YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            }
        }).setApplicationName("APP_ID").build();

        String apiKey = "API Key";
        YouTube.Videos.List listVideosRequest = youtube.videos().list("statistics");
        listVideosRequest.setId("qUvPzjSWMSM");
        listVideosRequest.setKey(apiKey);
        VideoListResponse listResponse = listVideosRequest.execute();

        Video video = listResponse.getItems().get(0);

        BigInteger viewCount = video.getStatistics().getViewCount();
        BigInteger Likes = video.getStatistics().getLikeCount();
        BigInteger DisLikes = video.getStatistics().getDislikeCount();
        BigInteger Comments = video.getStatistics().getCommentCount();
        System.out.println("[View Count] " + viewCount);
        System.out.println("[Likes] " + Likes);
        System.out.println("[Dislikes] " + DisLikes);
        System.out.println("[Comments] " + Comments);

        CommentThreadListResponse videoCommentsListResponse = youtube.commentThreads()
                .list("snippet").setVideoId("qUvPzjSWMSM").setMaxResults(50l).setTextFormat("plainText").execute();

        List<CommentThread> videoComments = videoCommentsListResponse.getItems();

            for (CommentThread videoComment : videoComments) {             
                CommentSnippet  snippet = videoComment.getSnippet().getTopLevelComment().getSnippet();
                System.out.println("  - Author: " + snippet.getAuthorDisplayName());
                System.out.println("  - Comment: " + snippet.getTextDisplay());
                System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            }


    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
        System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                + e.getDetails().getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("There was an IO error: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

FYI: So much of question that I have been through so far talk about adding `listVideosRequest.setKey(apiKey);` which I have it done. I also Have enable OAuth 2.0 enabled in my google console.

Comment: I assume your `apiKey` isn't really an `"API Key"`?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov well in that case then why am I getting the proper output result for, video Views, likes, dislikes? or if you mean that I might have `API key` in my actual code well then I don't, I have my very real google console api key.

Comment: which one of the calls is failing?  Remember API key is only used for accessing Public data.  If any of your calls are accessing private user data you will need to be using Oauth2 and authencating a user.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov my second call fails while trying to get the video comments. BTW calling for a video comment is private or public? can you redirect to an OAuth 2.0 and api key privileges link?

Comment: Thy seeing what detailed error say (`getDetails().getErrors()`). It should have an error code which you should be able to trace [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#common)

Comment: Why don't you use OAuth instead of API Key? I think this will resolve your problem. What I'm seeing here is that API Key does not provide enough authorization for what you're trying to do. So use OAuth instead.

Comment: @noogui hey thx for your recommendation. so i did had my research about OAuth. Anyway can you tell me where do u put the oauth `client ID` & `client Secret` at. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35441093/view-all-comments-on-a-youtube-video but it doesn't show where do u need to put those keys at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DalmTo for throwing to its direction.

Basically Api Key doesn't have priviledges to retrieve comments and things like that. for deep priviledges I had to use Oauth, which basically is being created the same was as  API Key but in Oauth you receive a client_secrets.json file containing: client secret, client ID and etc...

Then you call that in you code.

Note: Their is verious ways of calling you client_secrets.json file but it depends on your need.

My way: `Reader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream("/home/Downloads/src/client_secrets.json"));`